# How to get selected row index of ASP.NET DataGrid Control in JavaScript Method?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, datagrid

There is a DataGrid used in Default.aspx and Requirement is to get the text of all columns of selected row in a javascript method to copy it to clipboard. Currently, I'm doing this task but it selects all the rows of Grid and Past all data to Clipboard.

Default.aspx (Sample File)

```
<asp:GridView ID="ObjList" runat="server" OnLoad="xyz" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="ObjList_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false"> 
<Columns>
  .
  .
  .
</Columns>
```

Sample Button which calls javascript method to copy data to clipboard.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="BtnCopyToClipboard" ToolTip="Copy To Clipboard"   ImageUrl="img/tlb_list_copy.gif" OnClientClick="CopyGridView('ObjList'); return false;" runat="server" />
```

Sample JavaScript Function:

```
function CopyGridView(gridId) {
var div = document.getElementById(gridId);

var sSelectedRowText = div.Rows[iPL_SelectedRowIndex].Value;
if (div != null) {
    div.contentEditable = 'true';
    var controlRange;
    if (document.body.createControlRange) {
        controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
        controlRange.addElement(div);
        controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
        alert(InfoMsgClipboard);
    }
    div.contentEditable = 'false';
}
}
```

Any suggestion, how to identify selected row in grid and only copy selected row data in clipboard.

Comment: What are you using to select the row?

Comment: See it's going to be a jQuery/Java-Script code. So you will have to look how you can differentiate your selected row with other rows. Means the css class or something else and on the basis of it you can find the value. Just an idea

Answer (score 4):

```
function setSelectedRowId(RowId){
        document.getElementById("txtRowId").value = RowId; }

    private void ObjList_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.SelectedItem)
       {
          e.Item.Attributes.Add("onclick", "setSelectedRowId('" + e.Item.Cells[0].Text + "');
       }
```

Comment: Where I need to call this event "ObjList_ItemDataBound" ?

Comment: Add a OnItemDataBound="ObjList_ItemDataBound" inside the attributes of your datagrid, and it will use that ObjList_ItemDataBound method when bound.